# Why does my Navbar content in Bootstrap not show up when I click the hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

Quick question. When I click the hamburger button in bootstrap, the content doesn't slide down. I was following a tutorial on it, and couldn't tell what I was missing on this. Am I missing something in the button tag? Everything else is working fine. Any ideas?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Schenck Guitars</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap 5</a>
        <button
         class="navbar-toggler"
         type="button"
         data-bs-toggle="collapse"
         data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu"
         aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu"
         aria-expanded="false"
         aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suppert</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: upgrade bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing bootstrap 4 and 5. I changed this (which is syntax for BS 5):

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse"
data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu"
```

to this (which is syntax for BS 4):

```
data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#toggleMobileMenu"
```

You can of course go the other direction and switch to BS 5 CDN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Schenck Guitars</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap 5</a>
        <button
         class="navbar-toggler"
         type="button"
         data-toggle="collapse"
         data-target="#toggleMobileMenu"
         aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu"
         aria-expanded="false"
         aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suppert</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```